# Weierstrass M-test, Banach spaces, and absolute convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

As per the Weiestrass M-test, if absolute convergence of the series associated with a sequence in some normed vector space $X$ implies convergence of the series, then $X$ is Banach. However, I think it can be proved that if a series converges absolutely then it necessarily converges. So what is the point I'm missing here?

Comment: Do you want a counterexample (i.e. a series that converges absolutely but doesn't converge) or what are you asking precisely?

Comment: I'd appreciate a counterexample.

Comment: Can you clarify which result you're citing? It's not clear how one can conclude that a metric space is a Banach space without some additional structure. (Is $X$ even a vector space?)

Comment: @sequence Alright, one counterexample coming up.

Comment: @Bungo Thanks for pointing that out. I've just edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider $c_{00}$, the space of all sequences that are eventually zero. Put the supremum norm on $c_{00}$ and let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence in $c_{00}$ such that 
$$
a_n(m) =\left\{ \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{n!} & \text{ if } m =n \\ 0 & \text{ else } \end{matrix} \right.
$$
Clearly, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_n \in c_{00}$. Also note that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \| a_n\|_{\infty} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} = e,
$$
so the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ clearly converges absolutely, but it won't converge in $c_{00}$.

Comment: So, in my understanding, $\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty \left\| a_n(m)-a_k(m) \right\|_\infty=\left\| \frac{1}{n!}-\frac{1}{k!} \right\|_\infty$. Why can't we find $N\in \mathbb N$ such that $n, k\ge N\implies \left| \frac{1}{n!}-\frac{1}{k!} \right|<\varepsilon$?

Comment: Why are you summing over $m$ in there? What are you trying to do here, show that that $\left( \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \right)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $c_{00}$?

Comment: Why doesn't $a_n$ converge in $c_{00}$ if $\frac{1}{n!}\to 0$ when $n\to \infty$?

Comment: Well of course the sequence $(a_n)_n$ converges to zero in $c_{00}$, but the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ doesn't. Look at it this way, for a fixed $n \in \mathbb{n}$ we have that 
$\sum_{k=1}^n a_n = (1, 1/2!, 1/3!, \ldots, 1/n!, 0,0, \ldots)$. This doesn't converge in $c_{00}$ because the sequence $(1, 1/2!, 1/3!, \ldots, 1/n!, 1/(n+1)!, 1/(n+2)!, \ldots)$ isn't in $c_{00}$.

Answer (score 4):

For a general counterexample take a non-Banach space $X$.

Let $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$ which is not convergent.

There exists a subsequence $(x_{p(n)})_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\|x_{p(n+1)} - x_{p(n)}\| = \frac{1}{2^n}$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now define a sequence $(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ as

$$y_1 = x_{p(1)}$$
$$y_n = x_{p(n+1)} - x_{p(n)}, \text{ for } n \ge 2$$

and consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n$.

It certainly converges absolutely since:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|y_n\| = \|x_{p(1)}\| + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \|x_{p(n+1)} - x_{p(n)}\| \le \|x_{p(1)}\| + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac1{2^n} = \|x_{p(1)}\| + \frac12 < +\infty$$

However, it does not converge:

$$\sum_{n=1}^N y_n = x_{p(N+1)} - x_{p(1)}$$

This converges when $N \to \infty$ if and only if the sequence $(x_{p(n)})_{n=1}^\infty$ converges, which cannot be true since then the entire sequence $(x_{n})_{n=1}^\infty$ would converge.

Comment: But isn't it true that if $\sum_k \|x_k\|$ converges then $\forall\varepsilon >0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\ge N\implies  \sum_{k=n}^\infty \|x_k\|<\varepsilon$, then this implies that $\left\| \sum_{k=n}^\infty x_k\right\| \le \sum_{k=n}^\infty \|x_k\|<\varepsilon$, by triangle inequality?

Comment: @sequence Yes, it is true, but it only implies that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_k$ is Cauchy, not that it converges. Remember you are working in a non-Banach space.